# get all keys from nested json file (python)

Tags: python, json

Im tr

```
{
  "results": [{

    "firstName": "Emma",
    "href": "https://192.168.1.198:8904/api/cardholders/569",
    "id": "569",
    "lastName": "Bennett"
  } {
    "authorised": true,
    "firstName": "Dory",
    "id": "570",
    "lastName": "mcKormick"
  }]
```

In the end i want a list with all keys present: authorised, firstName, href, id, lastName

i just do not seem to get it trought iterations, using the .key() method. Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Why isn't `results` in the desired list? It's one of the keys.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and fix your spelling and finish your sentences. I don't think "I'm tr" is what you meant to say. Also, please provide us with examples of what you tried to do.

Comment: To add to what @Barmar said, why isn't `href` also in the desired list?

Comment: _i just do not seem to get it trought iterations, using the .key() method_ Show us what you tried.  Otherwise we cannot say what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `set` to prevent duplicates. Then loop through all the dictionaries, adding the keys to the set.

```
data = {
  "results": [{

    "firstName": "Emma",
    "href": "https://192.168.1.198:8904/api/cardholders/569",
    "id": "569",
    "lastName": "Bennett"
  }, {
    "authorised": True,
    "firstName": "Dory",
    "id": "570",
    "lastName": "mcKormick"
  }]
}

keys = set()
for d in data['results']:
    keys |= d.keys()

print(keys)
# Output: {'authorised', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'href', 'id'}
```

This assumes there's just one list of dictionaries, not arbitrary nesting depth. For the latter you'll need to write a recursive function.